# How can I move a word within a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a "native" way in Python 2.7 to move a word (space-delimited substring) within a longer string? Basically, what I'm looking for is:

```
ret = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.move_word('quick',2)
# ret = 'The brown fox quick jumps over the lazy dog'
```

My thought is to go about it by writing a function to split into a list, iterate through the list for matches, and then reorder as I find the word. My question is really about finding out if there are "slick"/Pythonic ways to do this instead.

Thanks!

EDIT: Per comments below: the numeric parameter in the example above was intended to specify a "delta" in number of words. For the above example, 2 was meant to mean "move 'quick' 2 words to the right".

Comment: No, there are no shortcuts. I think you are on the right way.

Comment: what does the 2 mean? move to position 2, move forward 2, backward 2?

Comment: Apologies for lack of clarity - I intended for the numeric parameter to represent a "delta" in terms of word position, so in the example I gave above, the intent would be to move the word that matches 'quick' 2 words later in the string. I will leave the question as-is as the comments assume different specs (unless it's better etiquette to edit the question).

Comment: I think it would be better to edit the question.  The example you give already assumes a delta -- making that explicit is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if I'd call this "slick", but it does the job and is pretty straightforward:

```
def reorder(s, word, delta):
  words = s.split()
  oldpos = words.index(word)
  words.insert(oldpos+delta, words.pop(oldpos))
  return ' '.join(words)

print reorder('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'quick', 2)
```

(I assume that the 2 in your example is the number of positions by which to move the word.)

Comment: `words.insert(..., words.pop(...))` makes me nervous.

Comment: @SamMussmann I'm assuming your nervousness is due to pop modifying the list and invalidating the index, correct?

Comment: @Bryan Yes.  After carefully thinking this through, I don't think it will be an issue, but if I were writing this, I wouldn't have the `pop` inside the `insert`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this

```
r = lambda x, y, z: " ".join(x.split(" ")[0:x.split(" ").index(y)] + x.split(" ")[x.split(" ").index(y)+1:x.split(" ").index(y)+z] + [x.split(" ")[x.split(" ").index(y)]] + x.split(" ")[x.split(" ").index(y)+z:])
```

is probably **NOT** pythonic, but it is fun.

(not to mention highly not optimal)

Comment: (probably adding a `lambda` for the split would be a good idea)

Comment: *Probably not* Pythonic? And must be some definition of "fun" - I've never heard of ;)

Comment: Well, why keep things simple when you can put everything in a looooong (and slow) one-liner? :P

Comment: My head hurts a little bit from following that, but very interesting nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do. It splits the string into a list, moves the item, then joins it back together:

```
def move_word(s, word, pos):
   split = s.split()
   split.insert(pos, split.pop(split.index(word)))
   return ' '.join(split)
```

Here's an example:

```
>>> s = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>> move_word(s, 'quick', 2)
'The brown quick fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>> move_word(s, 'jumps', 0)
'jumps The quick brown fox over the lazy dog'
```